# Windows 7, Mapped network drive permanent disconnect?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, time-capsule

I mapped a network drive to my Apple Time Capsule as `T`, but due to some configuration problems I had (but have fixed) it wouldn't reconnect at login.

In one of my tests I mapped the same drive as `Z` and left `reconnect at login` checked on accident.

Now, `Z` connects fine at login, but `T` doesn't.  When I reboot, they both show up, but `T` is disconnected and `Z` isn't.  I would like to permanently remove `Z` and make `T` the only mapped drive to the Time Capsule.
I can temporarily make the changes, (`T` connects fine if I manually do it no matter if `Z` is connected or not) but they revert back when I reboot.

I want to make `Z` go away forever and redo the `T` connection.  How can I do that on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
net use z: /d /y
reg delete HKCU\Network\Z /f
```

should remove all traces of it. If the drive doesn't disappear then reboot, and it should be gone when you log back in.

Comment: the first part removed it, but the 2nd part says it can't find that registry value.  Haven't had a chance to reboot yet (too much work open) so I can't test if it got rid of it completely, but thank you so far!

Comment: @Pselus: It says so precisely because the first command removed it. I only included `reg delete` in case there were any leftovers, but generally `net use ... /d` is enough.